# Linear Equation Problem answer

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Having trouble with a linear equation.

The equation I have been given is:

$5n+7 = 31-3n$

I keep coming up with $n = 12$ which makes sense because I was told in the following example to subtract the like terms.

$7x+15=3x-1$

Which is of course $x = -4$.

So I am being told that $n = 3$ which I can understand why it would when you ADD the like terms in the first equation but I was told to subtract. Am I wrong? or is this answer wrong - and if I am wrong what rule am I missing that would have me add like terms instead?

Comment: Adding $3n$ to both sides is the same as subtracting $-3n$ from both sides.  But, just like you, I prefer to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bunch up like terms on either side of the equation, so you want the terms containing $n$ to be all on one side, so you get

\begin{align}
5n+7&=31-3n\\
\Longrightarrow 5n+(3n)&=31-7\\
\Longrightarrow 8n&=24.
\end{align}
You can easily solve it from there.

**Note.** If they said subtract, then they may mean subtract $-3n$ from both sides, which of course means to add $3n$ since $-(-3n)=3n$.

Comment: Ah, entirely makes sense. I overlooked that it was -3n which to cancel out needs +3n. Because if I took 3n from -3n I'd be left with -6n. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{array} {cc}
5n+7 = 31-3n & \text{Add } 3n \text{ to both sides} \\
5n + 7 + 3n = 31 - 3n + 3n & \\
8n + 7 = 31 &  \text{Subtract } 7 \text{ from both sides} \\
8n + 7 - 7 = 31 - 7&  \\
8n = 24 &  \text{Divide both sides by } 8 \\
8n \div 8 = 24 \div 8 &  \\
n = 3  &  \\
\end{array}$$